# The variable is not protected

Tags: perl

i have this sources
first start.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use hh;

print "Starting...\n";

my $abc={
    VAL=>['alfa','beta'],
    STUDENTS=>{
        stud1=>{VAL=>['delta','gama']},
        stud2=>{VAL=>['omega','upsilon']},
            }
    };
my $object=hh->new(catalog=>$abc);
```

and the package

```
package hh;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class=shift;
    my $self={@_};
    bless ($self,$class) ; 
    $self->_initialize("",['BEGIN']);
    return $self ; 
}




sub _initialize {
    my $self=shift;
    my $tab=shift;
    my $carry=shift;
    $tab=$tab."\t|";
    
    if (defined $self->{VAL}){print "$tab Have  val=",join(" ",@{$self->{VAL}}),"\n";push(@{$carry},@{$self->{VAL}})}
    foreach my $k (sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} keys %{$self}){
        print $tab,"carry=",$#{$carry}+1," "," ",$k,"\n";
        if (ref($self->{$k}) eq 'HASH'){print "$tab Running initialize pentru $k\n";_initialize($self->{$k},$tab,$carry)}
    }

return $self;
}

1;
```

the output is like this

```
Starting...
    |carry=1  catalog
    | Running initialize pentru catalog
    |   | Have  val=alfa beta
    |   |carry=3  STUDENTS
    |   | Running initialize pentru STUDENTS
    |   |   |carry=3  stud1
    |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud1
    |   |   |   | Have  val=delta gama
    |   |   |   |carry=5  VAL
    |   |   |carry=5  stud2
    |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud2
    |   |   |   | Have  val=omega upsilon
    |   |   |   |carry=7  VAL
    |   |carry=7  VAL
```

Somehow i want to collect into an array  the VAL arrays between top of tree and the walked element . Way the last VAL who is in the second level has 7 elements .  I want to have only 2 elements (alfa and beta)

this is the expected output

> ```
> Starting...
>     |carry=1  catalog
>     | Running initialize pentru catalog
>     |   | Have  val=alfa beta
>     |   |carry=3  STUDENTS
>     |   | Running initialize pentru STUDENTS
>     |   |   |carry=3  stud1
>     |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud1
>     |   |   |   | Have  val=delta gama
>     |   |   |   |carry=5  VAL   carry=5                  (OK)
>     |   |   |carry=5  stud2
>     |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud2
>     |   |   |   | Have  val=omega upsilon
>     |   |   |   |carry=7  VAL      carry=5   (not ok this need only his values catalog alfa beta omega epsilon)
>     |   |carry=7  VAL not ok (carry 3  only catalog alfa beta)
> ```

...

Comment: *"Somehow i want to collect in a array or something the VAL arrays from the root of hash"* Since you are passing the array ref recursively to `_initialize()` the array is accumulating the `VAL` entries and for the last called it will contain 7 elements `BEGIN`, `alfa`, `beta`, `delta`, `gama`, `omega`, and `upsilon`

Comment: Please describe what the program is trying to do. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to walk entier tree and on each branch  i want to know all arrays who is between element and the top of tree

Comment: Can you show expected output? This will help clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accumulate only the values in the current branch, you have to pass a copy of the carry array. `[@$carry]` dereferences the arrayref `$carry` and creates a new arrayref from the elements. I kept the original reference for the debug print at the end of the function. The more natural way would be to write `$carry = [@$carry]`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package hh;
use Data::Dumper;
sub new {
    my $class=shift;
    my $self={@_};
    bless ($self,$class) ; 
    $self->_initialize("",['BEGIN']);
    return $self ; 
}




sub _initialize {
    my $self=shift;
    my $tab=shift;
    my $carry=shift;
    $tab=$tab."\t|";
    print "$tab _initialize() called with carry "," [",join(', ',@$carry),"]\n";
    my $new_carry =  [@$carry];
    if (defined $self->{VAL}){
        print "$tab Have found val=",join(" ",@{$self->{VAL}}),"\n";
        print "$tab pushing ",join(" ",@{$self->{VAL}}),"\n";
        push(@{$new_carry},@{$self->{VAL}})
    }
    print $tab," carry=",$#{$new_carry}+1," [",join(', ',@$new_carry),"]\n";

    foreach my $k (sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} keys %{$self}){
        if (ref($self->{$k}) eq 'HASH'){print "$tab Running initialize pentru $k\n";_initialize($self->{$k},$tab, $new_carry)}
    }
    print "$tab returning to previous level. carry was "," [",join(', ',@$carry),"]\n";
    return $self;
}

package main;
print "Starting...\n";

my $abc={
    VAL=>['alfa','beta'],
    STUDENTS=>{
        stud1=>{VAL=>['delta','gama']},
        stud2=>{VAL=>['omega','upsilon']},
            }
    };
my $object=hh->new(catalog=>$abc);
```

This prints:

```
Starting...
    | _initialized called with carry  [BEGIN]
    | carry=1 [BEGIN]
    | Running initialize pentru catalog
    |   | _initialized called with carry  [BEGIN]
    |   | Have found val=alfa beta
    |   | pushing alfa beta
    |   | carry=3 [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   | Running initialize pentru STUDENTS
    |   |   | _initialized called with carry  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   | carry=3 [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud1
    |   |   |   | _initialized called with carry  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   |   | Have found val=delta gama
    |   |   |   | pushing delta gama
    |   |   |   | carry=5 [BEGIN, alfa, beta, delta, gama]
    |   |   |   | returning to previous level. carry was  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   | Running initialize pentru stud2
    |   |   |   | _initialized called with carry  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   |   | Have found val=omega upsilon
    |   |   |   | pushing omega upsilon
    |   |   |   | carry=5 [BEGIN, alfa, beta, omega, upsilon]
    |   |   |   | returning to previous level. carry was  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   |   | returning to previous level. carry was  [BEGIN, alfa, beta]
    |   | returning to previous level. carry was  [BEGIN]
    | returning to previous level. carry was  [BEGIN]
```